# Security message on my app, when user login

Tags: facebook, authentication, message, facebook-login

I am getting this message:
"Please treat the URL above as you would your password and do not share it with anyone"

When my users are login to my app.
I looked at the code while debugging and saw that the retaining url does not include the access token anymore. I looked at the graph api documents and didnt see any changes there.

Did anyone encounter this message?
How can I avoid it? and get the access_token...?

Thanks
AsGr

Comment: http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/search?q=Please+treat+the+URL+above+as+you+would+your+password+and+do+not+share+it+with+anyone

Comment: does not helped me... saw it before... people there didnt solve the problem too.... is there any other solutions?